# Why iframe doesn't reload onclick?

Tags: javascript, iframe, onclick

I want to reload an iframe with a click on it.
A code, which can do so, doesn't work without any error
I've tried many times. Also with Jquery.

```
<iframe src='run.php' id='a' onclick="this.contentWindow.location.reload(true); "></iframe>
```

No error on Edge, Opera, no work. All variants.